# Where can I find help about FTTP broadband?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask the following.

> **Can I connect our external FTTP optical fibre to the WAN port on our router?**
>
> We have BT Fibre to the Premises, FTTP, and a Unifi Dream Machine Pro, UDMP. Currently, the BT connection terminates at a Nokia ONT, which hands off an RJ45 which is connected to the UDMP with a cat6a patch cable. As far as I can tell, the ONT is just like any other media converter, so can I cut out the middle man and connect the BT optical fibre directly to an SFP port on the UDMP? This would ensure that we have fibre directly into the network.
>
> I know I could just try it, however we do not have any SFP modules spare and don't want to buy one unnecessarily. I have also asked BT, but their representative did not know what SFP was.

I think this could either go in [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour), but I was not sure. If it is not suitable for either of those, I would be most grateful of a poke in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I have now asked this at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1675521/494499) as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Super User. This is pretty much a consumer side question, as opposed to a sysadmin even if you're talking about this at work.